# android creating and editing JSON dynamically

Tags: android, json

How to create JSON file in android ? 
I would like to create this kind looking JSON.

```
 {
"contacts": [
    {
            "id": "c200",
            "name": "Ravi Tamada",
            "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",

    },
    {
            "id": "c201",
            "name": "Johnny Depp",
            "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",

    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

]
}

Well i can create JSONObjects but cant figure out how to wrap that in "contacts" array.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {
    json.put("id", dataList.get(pos).id);
    json.put("name", dataList.get(pos).name);
   .
   .
   .
 String jsonString = json.toString();
 //and then save it
 FileOutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput("jsonfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fos.write(jsonString.getBytes());
                    fos.close();
```

And when i will read json back, can i edit json, like deleting JSONObject from middle, add new item at the end etc.?

Answer (score 0):

use jsonarray by using   `JSONArray array` and put the object to the array like you did it in
jsonobject

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    try {
        json.put("id", dataList.get(pos).id);
        json.put("name", dataList.get(pos).name);

     array.put("contacts", json );
```